# Update array object values based on another array items

Tags: javascript

I have this lst, which has the name and total available.

```
let lst = [
  { name: 'Apple', total: 4 },
  { name: 'Mango', total: 9 },
  { name: 'Orange', total: 6 },
  { name: 'Passion', total: 2 }
]
```

Now there is a new list json which I receive from an api, that only has names of the items, I changed to an array like this.

```
let newlst = ["Apple","Orange","Banana","Mango","Apple","Pineapple","Passion"]
```

So how do I go on about for each item in `newlst` that is found in `lst` array then sum their total +1 .... If not then skip.

So expected out is

```
let lst = [
  { name: 'Apple', total: 6 },
  { name: 'Mango', total: 10 },
  { name: 'Orange', total: 7 },
  { name: 'Passion', total: 3 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the *lst* and update the *total* by counting the fruits in the *newlst* using `filter()`

```js
let lst = [
  { name: 'Apple', total: 4 },
  { name: 'Mango', total: 9 },
  { name: 'Orange', total: 6 },
  { name: 'Passion', total: 2 }
];
let newlst = ["Apple","Orange","Banana","Mango","Apple","Pineapple","Passion"];

lst.forEach(function(fruit){
  //get the count in newlst
  let count = newlst.filter(f => f == fruit.name).length;
  //update the total by adding
  fruit.total = fruit.total + count;
});

console.log(lst);
```

Comment: why `forEach` not `map`? why `==` instead of `===`?

Comment: @Vulwsztyn, not any particular reason. I thought this could be easier for OP to understand:)

Comment: For every item in `lst` you again and again filter `newlst`, which is an O(N*M) solution. It could have been more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by loop also. compare the array elements and json object name and than increase the total of that corresponding json object.

```
let lst = [
  { name: 'Apple', total: 4 },
  { name: 'Mango', total: 9 },
  { name: 'Orange', total: 6 },
  { name: 'Passion', total: 2 }
];
let newlst = ["Apple","Orange","Banana","Mango","Apple","Pineapple","Passion"];
for(i=0;i<lst.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<newlst.length;j++){
         if(lst[i].name === newlst[j]){
            lst[i].total++;
          }    
    }
 }
 console.log(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `let` instead of `const`? you shouldn't
You could do it like this

```
lst.map(({ name, total }) => ({ name, total: total + newlst.filter((x) => x === name).length }))
```

```js
const lst = [
  { name: 'Apple', total: 4 },
  { name: 'Mango', total: 9 },
  { name: 'Orange', total: 6 },
  { name: 'Passion', total: 2 }
]

const newlst = ["Apple","Orange","Banana","Mango","Apple","Pineapple","Passion"]
console.log(lst.map(({ name, total }) => ({ name, total: total + newlst.filter((x) => x === name).length })))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` to create a keyValue pair and update all the existing values in an efficient way.

```js
Const dict = new Map()
lst.forEach(item => dict.set(item.name, item))
```

When you receive the new array

```js
newlst.forEach(item => {
   if(!dict.has(item)) { // true if you receive a new element not present in lst
       const newObj = {name: item, total: 0}
       dict.set(item, newObj); 
       lts.push(newObj)
   }
   dict.get(item).total++;
})
```

Since you haven't changed the reference your initial array has now all the values updated.
This will be O(n) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `Map` out of `newlst` whose keys represent they **fruit name** and values represent the **fruit count**.
2. Loop over `lst` and check if the current fruit is in the `Map` then increment count otherwise leave as is.

```js
let lst = [{ name: "Apple", total: 4 }, { name: "Mango", total: 9 }, { name: "Orange", total: 6 }, { name: "Passion", total: 2 }];

let newlst = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Mango", "Apple", "Pineapple", "Passion"];

const m = newlst.reduce((r, f) => r.set(f, (r.get(f) || 0) + 1), new Map());

console.log(
  lst.map((f) => (m.has(f.name) ? { ...f, total: f.total + m.get(f.name) } : f))
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @TM678

Answer (score 0):

```js
let lst = [
  { name: 'Apple', total: 4 },
  { name: 'Mango', total: 9 },
  { name: 'Orange', total: 6 },
  { name: 'Passion', total: 2 },
  { name: 'test', total: 1 }
];
let newlst = ["Apple","Orange","Banana","Mango","Apple","Pineapple","Passion"];

lst.map(el=>{
  newlst.indexOf(el.name)>-1 ? el.total=el.total+1 : el
});
console.log(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `map` through the `list` and filter out items in the `newList` based on the item being mapped in the `list`. The length of the filter output will give us the number of occurrences of the item in the `newList` and based on that we can derive the `total` logic.

```js
const list = [{name: 'Apple', total: 4}, {name: 'Mango', total: 9}, 
{name: 'Orange', total: 6}, {name: 'Passion', total: 2}];

const newList = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Passion'];

const result = list.map((x) => {
  const numberOfOccurences = newList.filter((y) => y === x.name).length
  return {
    ...x,
    total: x.total + numberOfOccurences
  };
});

console.log(result);
```